# R split string into elements, sort and recombine

Tags: r, data.table

The basic problem I'm trying to solve has been done for a single character vector and a character vector within a data frame. I'm trying to do it for a data table because I have a lot of columns that are a single string with multiple elements so I'd like to do this in memory without making copies. In the code below I tried to follow the approach taken at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337732/r-sort-a-string-of-items-alphabetically).

```
test <- data.table(col1 = c("cow, pig, horse"), col2 = c("fish, aardvark, moose"))
test2 <- data.table(col1 = c("orange, pig, frog"), col2 = c("whale, aardvark, elk"))
test <- rbind(test, test2)
cols <- c("col1", "col2")

test[, (cols) := (lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  paste(sort(trimws(strsplit(x, ',')[[1]])), collapse=',')
  })), .SDcols = cols]
```

What I end up with is the first row, sorted, in both rows. Help, please, and with a bit of explanation of what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a second *apply to loop through elements of x.

```
test[, (cols) := (lapply(.SD, function(x) {
   #browser()
   sapply(x, function(y) paste(sort(trimws(strsplit(y, ',')[[1]])), collapse=','))
})), .SDcols = cols]

> test
              col1                col2
1:   cow,horse,pig aardvark,fish,moose
2: frog,orange,pig  aardvark,elk,whale
```

`strsplit(x, ',')[[1]]` used the first element from each column, as you can see below

```
Browse[1]> strsplit(x, ',')
[[1]]
[1] "cow"    " pig"   " horse"

[[2]]
[1] "orange" " pig"   " frog"

Browse[1]> strsplit(x, ',')[[1]]
[1] "cow"    " pig"   " horse"
```

Comment: The order of nesting here will make a big difference to speed. `strsplit` should only need to be called twice rather than for each row. E.g.: `sortcomb <- function(x) lapply(strsplit(x, ",\\s+"), function(v) paste(sort(v), collapse=","));
  testbig[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, sortcomb), .SDcols=cols]` should be a lot quicker.