# Merge rows containing similar strings using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table containing the following data:

```
df <- tibble(
  dose = seq(10, 50, 10), 
  date = c("2007-12-15", "2007-10-13","2007-10-13","2007-09-30","2007-09-30"), 
  response = c(45, 67, 66, 54, 55), 
  name = c("Peter,Martin", "Gale,Rebecca", "Rebecca,Gale", "Jonathan,Smith", "Smith,Jonathan")
)
```

The table:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
   dose date       response name          
  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>         
1    10 2007-12-15       45 Peter,Martin  
2    20 2007-10-13       67 Gale,Rebecca  
3    30 2007-10-13       66 Rebecca,Gale  
4    40 2007-09-30       54 Jonathan,Smith
5    50 2007-09-30       55 Smith,Jonathan
```

One of the columns called `name` either has a string "FirstName,LastName" or "LastName,FirstName". I wish to merge the rows that contain the same names if they are ordered either way. For example, the rows containing Rebecca,Gale and Gale,Rebecca should merge.

While merging, I wish to get the sums of the columns `dose` and `response` and want to keep the first of the `date` and `name` entries.

**Expected outcome:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   dose date       response name          
  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>         
1    10 2007-12-15       45 Peter,Martin  
2    50 2007-10-13      133 Gale,Rebecca  
3    90 2007-09-30      109 Jonathan,Smith
```

Please note that I always want to merge using the `name` column and not the `date` column because even if the example contains the same dates, my bigger table has different dates for the same name.

Comment: You say "my bigger table has different dates for the same name": Which date should be kept in this cases?

Comment: The first one would be fine. Thanks

Comment: You could split the names by the comma, order them (alphabetically would be easiest), paste back together, and use that as the joining column. If you have a reference of which is the first & which is the last, you could use that instead as the way to order them

Comment: There's a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47337732/5325862)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one idea.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  mutate(name = map_chr(name, ~toString(sort(str_split(.x, ",")[[1]])))) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(dose = sum(dose),
            response = sum(response),
            date = first(date)) %>%
  select(names(df)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#    dose date       response name           
#   <dbl> <date>        <dbl> <chr>          
# 1    50 2007-10-13      133 Gale, Rebecca  
# 2    90 2007-09-30      109 Jonathan, Smith
# 3    10 2007-12-15       45 Martin, Peter
```

Comment: That is beautiful! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @www Truly beautiful! ;) Could I bother you to explain the `map_chr` and `toString` part of your answer a bit? I would love to learn about this! Thanks

Comment: @www  I got it now. the usage of `sort` to get a deterministic ordering of the words is quite elegant! and toString seems to be the same as `paste0(x, collapse=",")` ?

Comment: @dario You are right. `toString` works like `paste0(x, collapse=", ")`.